# Is it possible to use the for...of syntax for a for loop in observablehq?

Tags: javascript, observablehq

In regular `JavaScript`, one can write a `for loop` using the for...of syntax. Is this possible with `observablehq`?

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3];

for (const element of array1) {
  console.log(element);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in a single cell like so:

```js
array1 = {
  const array = [1, 2, 3];

  for (const element of array) {
    console.log(element);
  }

  return array;
}
```

**For any JavaScript syntax, all you have to do is wrap it in curly braces {…} (to make a block statement).**

Then, if you want to expose this value to other cells in your notebook, give that cell a name by adding `name =`  before the open curly brace, and return the desired value.

The other syntax you use is known as an expression cell:

```js
array1 = [1, 2, 3]
```

It’s just shorthand for the equivalent block cell:

```js
array1 = {
  return [1, 2, 3];
}
```

So depending how much code you want to put in the cell, you can either use an expression or a block (by adding curlies). But either way a cell can only have one name and one value.

Comment: "For any JavaScript syntax, all you have to do is wrap it in curly braces." is a great mental model. I must admit that when things did not work as expected, I often added some curly braces here and there, but admittedly was never sure where to put them, and if they are going to solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not really. As explained in the tutorials, [Observable is not [exactly] JavaScript](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/observables-not-javascript).

In your case, you need to do two things:

First, there is no `const`, just make a cell with `array1` value:

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3];
```

Then for the `for` loop, **in a separate cell**, put it between curly braces:

```
{
    for (const element of array1) {
        console.log(element);
    }
}
```

That cell, of course, will return `undefined`:

[image]

Comment: I tried to experiement with your solution a little bit, and realised that just adding curly braces around my example, the examplee works. Thanks!

Comment: @Jakub.Novotny that's another option, but then you cannot use `array1` in any other cell.

Comment: it seems like you actually can as demonstrated in mbostock's answer.

Comment: @Jakub.Novotny well, that guy literally created ObservableHQ, so he probably knows better!